# Element styled with CSS Flex box appears outside parent element and doesn't vertically align with parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `<section>` element with a title, that contains a `<div>` which holds some text. I need the `<div>` to appear in the middle of the `<section>` tag, and the `<section>` should take up the rest of the space under the header. To the user, the `<div>` should appear in the centre of the space under the header.

My following code does that to some degree, but it appears off-centre. I think thats's because I applied `height: 100vh` to the `<section>`, which makes that element longer than the rest of the page.

How do I achieve this? I'm trying to create a generic set of styles for the `div.message` so that I can drop it in when needed and it will appear in the centre of the area below the header.

```css
header {}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
}

.message {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
}

.message .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header area</h1>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <h2>This is a section</h2>
  <div class="message">
    <p class="text">This section is empty</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykz5Lvsk/1/)

Comment: Do you need the whole section centered or just the div inside it?

Comment: You want the <section> should take up the rest of the space under the header or the <div> to appear in the middle of the <section> tag? I saw the <div> already  appeared in the middle of the <section> tag.

Comment: @Duannx yes that's right, I believe I'll always need the `<section>` tag to take up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I recommend you do, and get a good responsive layout:

- Add a wrapper, the `container` (could also use the `body`)
- Make the `container` a flex column container so the `header` and `content` will stack vertically
- Set `flex-grow: 1` on `content` so if take the remaining space of its parent
- Make the `content` a flex column container
- Set `flex-grow: 1` on `message` so if take the remaining space of its parent
- Make the `message` a flex row container (the default)
- Set `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on `message` so its content centers

Finally, we need to take the `h2` out of flow or else the `message` won't fill its entire parent's height, and if not, the `message` won't center vertically in the `section`

*Note, as the `h2` is positioned absolute the `content` could also be set as a flex row container, though I choose to use "column" to make it move obvious compared with the markup structure*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj5mvmd1/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {}
.content {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.message {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.message .text {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* styles for this demo */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
}
header {
  border: 1px dotted red;  
}
.content {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.message,
.message .text {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Header area</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="content">
    <h2>This is a section</h2>
    <div class="message">
      <p class="text">This section is empty</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

---

Based on how you intend to use `message`, you could also set the `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to the `content` (and drop the flex properties on the `message`)

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vj5mvmd1/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {}
.content {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.content h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.message {
}

.message .text {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* styles for this demo */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
}
header {
  border: 1px dotted red;  
}
.content {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.message,
.text {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Header area</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="content">
    <h2>This is a section</h2>
    <div class="message">
      <p class="text">This section is empty</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

---

If the `message` is only a wrapper for the `p`, you could drop it all together.

[Fiddle demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/vj5mvmd1/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, this is what you're looking for :

```
header {

}
.content {
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.message {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.message .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;  
}
```

[The JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ykz5Lvsk/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two main ways of solving this:
1) If you assign a fixed height to the header, you can then give the section the remaining height with `calc`:

```
.header {
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

You will need to make sure it works even with smaller windows (you might need to add some media queries)

2) If you instead don't want to assign a fixed height to the header, you can wrap `header` and `section` into a common parent that is using a flexbox, and allow the `section` to grow. I wrote this solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/annc8w4j/1/